# Ionic 2/3 open native page - Android/iOS

Tags: android, ionic2, arcgis, ionic3

Im trying to open a native page, because i need to run an arcgis map using the native SDK, is there a way to execute an "openNativePage()" and run  a custom activity (android) in ionic 2?

I didnt see any plugin in the ionic framework to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need to create your own cordova-plugin for something like this. In your plugin you can create an `Intent` just like you are used to in Android development.

[Here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) you can find the offical docs on how to create a cordova-plugin. But you will want to look at some other plugins on e.g. github to get some inspiration.